# pyperclipがimportできません

Tags: python, python3, anaconda3

OS:windows10
Version:python3.6.5
(Anaconda3-5.2.0-Windows-x86_64.exeでインストールしました。)

pyperclipを使うコードの試行していましたが，うまく動かないのでインタラクティブシェルで
pyperclipをimportしたら，以下のエラーとなりました。

```
>>> import pyperclip
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import pyperclip
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyperclip'
```

anacnda3のインストールフォルダで「pyperclip」検索すると以下のようになります。

[image: pyperclip検索]

解決方法を教えてください。

試していたコードは以下のものです。

```
#! python3
# pw.py - パスワード管理プログラム（脆弱性あり）

PASSWORDS = {'email': 'F7minlBDDuvMJuxESSKHFhTxFtjVB6',
             'blog': 'VmALvQyKAxiVH5G8v01if1MLZF3sdt',
             'luggage': '12345'}

import sys
import pyperclip

if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    print('使い方: python pw.py [アカウント名]')
    print('パスワードをクリップボードにコピーします')
    sys.exit()

account = sys.argv[1] # 最初のコマンドライン引数がアカウント名

if account in PASSWORDS:
    pyperclip.copy(PASSWORDS[account])
    print(account + 'のパスワードをクリップボードにコピーしました')
else:
    print(account + 'というアカウント名はありません')
```

Comment: Pyperclip はどのようにインストールなさいましたか？

Comment: anaconda3の下にいくつかあったので，別途インストールするなとどは夢にも思っていませんでした。「C:\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\prompt_toolkit\clipboard」や「C:\Anaconda3\pkgs\prompt_toolkit-1.0.15-py36h60b8f86_0\Lib\site-packages\prompt_toolkit\clipboard」

Comment: conda install pyperclipをしましたが，エラーになります。これについて別件で質問を立てさせていただきたいと思います。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### 解決しました。

原因
インストールしていなかった

対策

1. インストールのため，プロキシ経由でcondaが動くようにした
   　- プロキシサーバを調べる
   　- .condarc作成

[プロキシ設定が「セットアップスクリプトを使う」がオンの場合のcondaによるインストールのための接続設定を教えてください](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/54019/%E3%83%97%E3%83%AD%E3%82%AD%E3%82%B7%E8%A8%AD%E5%AE%9A%E3%81%8C-%E3%82%BB%E3%83%83%E3%83%88%E3%82%A2%E3%83%83%E3%83%97%E3%82%B9%E3%82%AF%E3%83%AA%E3%83%97%E3%83%88%E3%82%92%E4%BD%BF%E3%81%86-%E3%81%8C%E3%82%AA%E3%83%B3%E3%81%AE%E5%A0%B4%E5%90%88%E3%81%AEconda%E3%81%AB%E3%82%88%E3%82%8B%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AB%E3%81%AE%E3%81%9F%E3%82%81%E3%81%AE%E6%8E%A5%E7%B6%9A%E8%A8%AD%E5%AE%9A%E3%82%92%E6%95%99%E3%81%88%E3%81%A6%E3%81%8F%E3%81%A0%E3%81%95%E3%81%84)

2. pyperclipはサードパーティーのモジュールなので，pipを使う
   　- pipもプロキシ経由

[proxyかんでる社内環境でpip/anacondaを動かすときに注意事項- Qiita](https://qiita.com/dev4kj/items/af6c0fea17adef514ba8)。

```
c:\>pip install pyperclip --proxy http://userID:password@round.net.×××.co.jp:8080
Collecting pyperclip
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/2d/0f/4eda562dffd085945d57c2d9a5da745cfb5228c02bc90f2c74bbac746243/pyperclip-1.7.0.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: pyperclip
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for pyperclip ... done
  Stored in directory: C:\Users\userID\AppData\Local\pip\Cache\wheels\92\f0\ac\2ba2972034e98971c3654ece337ac61e546bdeb34ca960dc8c
Successfully built pyperclip
distributed 1.21.8 requires msgpack, which is not installed.
Installing collected packages: pyperclip
Successfully installed pyperclip-1.7.0
You are using pip version 10.0.1, however version 19.0.3 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

pipが古いと怒られたものの，何とか解決です。

```
Python 3.6.5 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Mar 29 2018, 13:32:41) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> import pyperclip
>>>
```