# プロキシ設定が「セットアップスクリプトを使う」がオンの場合のcondaによるインストールのための接続設定を教えてください

Tags: python3, pip, anaconda3, conda

OS:windows10
Version:python3.6.5
(Anaconda3-5.2.0-Windows-x86_64.exeでインストールしました。)

pyperclipをインストールしようとしたところ，サイトにつながないようなので，プロキシ経由のせいで，.condarcが必要というところまで辿り着きました。会社のPCです。
プロキシ設定が「セットアップスクリプトを使う」がオンになっていて，「プロキシサーバーを使う」がオフになっていました。故にアドレスもポート番号もありません。
スクリプトのアドレスは以下の通りです。

```
http://www.net.×××.co.jp/proxy.pac
```

[Proxy下のWindowsでPython(Anaconda)環境を整える](https://qiita.com/mishan88/items/2f9e1c5e9e2572ba8a36)　を参考に，.condarcを作ってみました。

```
proxy_servers:
    http: http://www.net.×××.co.jp:8080
    https: https://www.net.×××.co.jp:8080
```

conda config --show　では

```
proxy_servers:
  http: http://www.net.×××.co.jp:8080
  https: https://www.net.×××.co.jp:8080
```

と出てきますが，インストール(conda install pyperclip)はダメでした。

プロキシ設定が「セットアップスクリプトを使う」がオンになっていて，「プロキシサーバーを使う」がオフになっている場合の設定の方法を教えてください。

エラーは以下の通りです。

```
CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url <https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/pro/win-64/repodata.json.bz2>
Elapsed: -

An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.

If your current network has https://www.anaconda.com blocked, please file
a support request with your network engineering team.

ProxyError(MaxRetryError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='repo.anaconda.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /pkgs/pro/win-64/repodata.json.bz2 (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0000019A94A87B38>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] 対象のコン ピューターによって拒否されたため、接続できませんでした。',)))",),)
```

Comment: 少し時間を置いて試してみたり、ブラウザから`https://www.anaconda.com`に接続できるか、などを確認してみてください。また、万一職場や学校のプロキシ環境などを経由している場合にはその辺りの情報も詳しく書いてあると回答の参考になるかもしれません。

Comment: 日にちを置いて何度か試したけれどダメでした。UACも一番甘くしましたが，ダメです。職場のPCなので

Comment: 参考: [認証付きプロキシ環境でcondaを使用する。 - Qiita](https://qiita.com/Kyohei_Yamaji/items/dcee95ade24e12fdfd91)

Comment: 会社のPCのプロキシ設定が「セットアップスクリプトを使う」がオンになっていて，「プロキシサーバーを使う」がオフになっていました。故にアドレスもポート番号もありません。(勝手に設定を変えていいものか不明です…)

Comment: 「外部ネットワークとの接続にプロキシを通る」は大事な情報なので、質問文を編集して直接追記してみてください (そうする事で回答してくれる人の目に留まりやすくなります)。 / プロキシのデフォルトポートは`8080`ですし、ホスト名も基本的には「セットアップスクリプト」に入力されているURLの`ホスト名`部分と同じになりそうな気がします。

Comment: ありがとうございます。取り敢えず，右も左もわからない状態から，.condarcまで辿り着けました。この上は，仰るように.condarcを編集して試してみます。それを踏まえて，プロキシ設定が「セットアップスクリプトを使う」の場合どうしたらいいかというように質問文を編集してみます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### 自動構成スクリプト(.pac)を確認できました

プロキシの自動構成スクリプト(.pac)を確認しました。
([プロキシ自動設定 - Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%97%E3%83%AD%E3%82%AD%E3%82%B7%E8%87%AA%E5%8B%95%E8%A8%AD%E5%AE%9A) は解り易かったです)

```
return  "PROXY round.net.×××.co.jp:8080";
```

.condarcを以下のように編集しました。

```
proxy_servers:
    http: http://Login-ID:password@round.net.×××.co.jp:8080
    https: https://Login-ID:password@round.net.×××.co.jp:8080
```

conda installを実行しました。
残念ながら該当モジュールはサードパーティーでcondaでインストールできなかったようですが，はじかれずに済みました。⇒ pipでインストールしました(追記)。

```
(base) C:\Users\Login-ID>conda install pyperclip
Solving environment: failed

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - pyperclip

Current channels:

  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/pro/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/pro/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

### 追記:サードパーティーのモジュールのインストール - pip

```
>pip install モジュール名 --proxy http://login-ID:password@プロキシサーバー名
```

Answer (score 3):

プロキシの自動構成スクリプト(.pac)の中に、アクセス先のURLに対応するプロキシのURLが記載されているはずです。

[プロキシ自動設定 - Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%97%E3%83%AD%E3%82%AD%E3%82%B7%E8%87%AA%E5%8B%95%E8%A8%AD%E5%AE%9A)

.pacをダウンロードしてテキストエディタで開けば確認できます。

また、ちょっと自信がないですが、Windows 10 ならPowershellで以下のコマンドを実行すると、URLに対応するプロキシのURLが取得できるのではないかとおもいます。（AbsoluteUriがプロキシのパスだったかと思います）

```
$URL = https://repo.anaconda.com
$SystemProxy = [System.Net.WebRequest]::GetSystemWebProxy()

$SystemProxy.GetProxy($URL)
```

proxyのURIさえ確認できれば、それを.condarcに記載すればいいのではないでしょうか。

Comment: ありがとうございます。おかげさまで通ったようです。手順を回答としておきたいと思います。